# Javascript exception in Selenium - Java - org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: [object Object]

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, relative-locators

The line in the code is:

```
a = driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("style")).toRightOf(By.tagName("colspan"))).getText();
```

There is a very long essay by way of error in the Console section, including am MIT license disclaimer (?)... I cannot make head or tail of it. I struggled making this line of code, I'm sure there must be some error in it. The goal is to get a net figure (bottom right) from an online table, but it's behind a login which I can't share.

When you hover over the html, there is a structure like

```
<head><body><table><tbody><tr><td><b>
```

The exact cell I need is on the <td> part, but the data in it is in the <b> part. There is no tag or anything in the <b> part. There is an iframe as well, but I verified that i'm on the correct one, as I do get the correct result using xpath. But I need a relative locator, because there are multiple pages with different tables, and they are dynamically generated and vary in size from day to day as well. I hope this was enough information... if not please ask for whatever else is needed...thank you! Here is a list of all the errors:

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator$RelativeBy.findElements(RelativeLocator.java:194)
at org.openqa.selenium.By.findElement(By.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$1.findElement(ElementLocation.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:349)
at artifactidshilpipackage.shilpi.main(shilpi.java:82)
```

Comment: You should try/catch the call and include the exception caught.  (It looks like there's an exception returned but you haven't listed it there...  probably no such element)  Right off the bat, though you won't want to use a relative locator on a <style> tag (has no location onscreen) and "colspan" is an attribute, not a HTML tag name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @pcalkins If you ignore my code, how would you typically relatively locate an html structure like I wrote? Basically, how to download a dynamic html table?

Comment: if the HTML markup of the DOM doesn't give you a good target, think about how the user decides what is what... hard to give more specific advice without seeing the markup.

Comment: those relative locators are pretty new.  I haven't used them yet.  They seem to be designed to test locations of objects (probably at different screen sizes).  I've never had a case where I needed to use them.  (and they do have a higher overhead than using other locators)

Comment: Yeah those might be wrong, like you said colspan is an attribute. So I want to try a new approach, to download the whole table. But I cannot figure out how to write excel tables from selenium, all the tutorials are of just one or two cells. How to write entire tables efficiently, getRow function has null pointer issues and createCell sometimes deletes other cells...

Comment: you can get a webreference array of all <td>'s using findElements() and parse accordingly.    It all depends on the markup of the DOM.